# how to input dataset from txt file in python for geoJSON

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda, geojson

I have very little experience with geoJSON and python scripting.

I'm trying to take in a txt file and convert it into data for a geoJSON dataset with these values.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220997/pandas-to-geojson-multiples-points-features-with-python

I referred to this article and I used this piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geojson

def data2geojson(df):
    features = []
    insert_features = lambda X: features.append(
            geojson.Feature(geometry=geojson.LineString((X["long"],
                                                    X["lat"],
                                                    X["elev"])),
                            properties=dict(name=X["name"],
                                            description=X["description"])))
    df.apply(insert_features, axis=1)
    with open('map1.geojson', 'w', encoding='utf8') as fp:
        geojson.dump(geojson.FeatureCollection(features), fp, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False,indent=4)

col = ['lat','long','elev','name','description']
data = [[-29.9953,-70.5867,760,'A','Place MNO'],
        [-30.1217,-70.4933,1250,'C','Place PQR'],
        [-30.0953,-70.5008,1185,'C','Place STU']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col)

data2geojson(df)
```

However for data, I have points that are in the same line (hence why I am using LineString instead of Point) and they have unique IDs to be placed in the 'properties' section of the geoJSON.

This is an example of the data in my .txt file

```
lat=1.3218368 ,long=103.9364834 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3218821 ,long=103.9364744 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3219285 ,long=103.9367017 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.321643 ,long=103.9364707 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3216271 ,long=103.9363887 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3235089 ,long=103.9344606 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3237205 ,long=103.9355026 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3217046 ,long=103.934106 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3203204 ,long=103.9366324 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3206557 ,long=103.9373536 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3206271 ,long=103.9374192 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3205511 ,long=103.9371742 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3206044 ,long=103.9375056 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3207561 ,long=103.9371863 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3204307 ,long=103.9368537 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3204877 ,long=103.9368389 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3205465 ,long=103.9368269 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.320612 ,long=103.9368246 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3207378 ,long=103.9371016 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3207702 ,long=103.9370846 ,B, Place AC
```

How should I go about with taking in this txt as the input for the function's `data` array and grouping them according to the `name` eg. A or B, regardless of `description` as `LineString` have more than 1 point attached to each object.

Any and all help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise using [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/), as it is tailored to issues like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import io

col = ['lat','long','name','description']
data = '''lat=1.3218368 ,long=103.9364834 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3218821 ,long=103.9364744 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3219285 ,long=103.9367017 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.321643 ,long=103.9364707 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3216271 ,long=103.9363887 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3235089 ,long=103.9344606 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3237205 ,long=103.9355026 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3217046 ,long=103.934106 ,A, Place BC
lat=1.3203204 ,long=103.9366324 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3206557 ,long=103.9373536 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3206271 ,long=103.9374192 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3205511 ,long=103.9371742 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3206044 ,long=103.9375056 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3207561 ,long=103.9371863 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3204307 ,long=103.9368537 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3204877 ,long=103.9368389 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3205465 ,long=103.9368269 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.320612 ,long=103.9368246 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3207378 ,long=103.9371016 ,B, Place AC
lat=1.3207702 ,long=103.9370846 ,B, Place AC'''

#load csv as dataframe (replace io.StringIO(data) with the csv filename), use converters to clean up lat and long columns upon loading
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), names=col, sep='\s*\,\s*', engine='python', converters={'lat': lambda x: float(x.split('=')[1]), 'long': lambda x: float(x.split('=')[1])})

#load dataframe as geodataframe
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.long, df.lat))
#groupby on name and description, while converting the grouped geometries to a LineString
gdf = gdf.groupby(['name', 'description'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist())).reset_index()

gdf.to_json()
```

Output geojson:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"id": "0", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"description": "Place BC", "name": "A"}, "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[103.9364834, 1.3218368], [103.9364744, 1.3218821], [103.9367017, 1.3219285], [103.9364707, 1.321643], [103.9363887, 1.3216271], [103.9344606, 1.3235089], [103.9355026, 1.3237205], [103.934106, 1.3217046]]}}, {"id": "1", "type": "Feature", "properties": {"description": "Place AC", "name": "B"}, "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[103.9366324, 1.3203204], [103.9373536, 1.3206557], [103.9374192, 1.3206271], [103.9371742, 1.3205511], [103.9375056, 1.3206044], [103.9371863, 1.3207561], [103.9368537, 1.3204307], [103.9368389, 1.3204877], [103.9368269, 1.3205465], [103.9368246, 1.320612], [103.9371016, 1.3207378], [103.9370846, 1.3207702]]}}]}
```